# Best way to make a subgraph with only mutual edges out of a directed graph

Tags: python, igraph

I'm working with a directed graph in the igraph python library.
I'm trying to get a subgraph containing only mutual edges.

My current Implementation is:

```
i = 0
edgeList = list()
for e in completeGraph.es:
    i = i+1
    if not e.is_mutual():
        edgeList.append(e)
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print(i)
completeGraph.delete_edges(edgeList)
completeGraph.vs.select(_degree=0).delete()
```

Which seems to work, but it feels like a very roundabout way of doing it, and on a very large graph (as the type i'm working on with ~20 Mio. Edges) it's fairly slow.

Is there a better or more efficient way of accomplishing the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a possible solution. I did it with Python 3.8.5 and igraph 0.9.1. I create a simple example, a directed graph with 10 vertices and 7 edges (4 mutuals). Maybe it  could help you.

```
from igraph import *

g = Graph(directed=True)
g.add_vertices(10)
g.add_edges([(0, 1), (1, 0), (5, 3), (7, 8), (9, 1), (7, 2), (2, 7)])

g.es.select(_is_mutual=False).delete()
g.vs.select(_degree=0).delete()
```

The result is that the graph g have only mutual edges (and vertices involved in those edges).

Good luck!